# GWT activities and places. External link always start default place

Tags: gwt

I have lost all the morning searching for this problem on internet and nobody seems to face this problem.

My GWT application navigate very well. But as a logic requirement on my application it generates an email with a link to my application. The link is something like this:

http://server#place:token

Well, it navigate always to the same DefaultPlace i declare on initialization.

I have write a lot of logs in the client side. And it ignores completely the request. Even if i type this url in the browser, it loads default place.

My application navigates very well between places internally but now i realize that it happens not only with one particular place, but any place.

Could some one help me to realize what would be the problem. I could write  the code if any want to see.

This is my PlacehistoryMapper:

```
@WithTokenizers({DefaultPlace.Tokenizer.class,
                 AuthenticationPlace.Tokenizer.class,
                 ProcessSnCallbackPlace.Tokenizer.class,
                 GatherUserInfoPlace.Tokenizer.class,
                 LoadProfilePlace.Tokenizer.class,
                 RegisterPlace.Tokenizer.class})
 public interface AppPlacesHistoryMapper extends PlaceHistoryMapper                 
 }
```

This is my ActivityMapper in getActivity override:

```
 @Override
public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
    Provider provider = getProvider(place); 
    if (provider == null) {
        browserUtils.log("Error: " +  place.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " Place is not mapped.");
        return null;
    }
    return (Activity) provider.get();
}
```

And all activities all injected by GIN and works fine. But always when debug the default place is the only i see in those line. However if i change the place by goTo it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Albert.

Comment: please provide the code here

Comment: I guess that you have to do `History.fireCurrentHistoryState();` after setting handlers.

Comment: I already set this with historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory()